# How fast could 1,767 cubic feet of fusion fuel propel a starship?

Tags: fusion, space-travel

I'm designing a starship that could go to Alpha Centauri in under 15 years. My design goes at a top speed of 0.5c. Assuming the fuel is in gaseous form, could this provide enough energy to propel it? (It needs to speed up, but not noticeably, since there's already an artificial gravity ring.)

Comment: We aren't even at the fusion energy break even point, so you're speculating about engines that don't yet exist. There are a lot of technical details one would need to know to get any reasonable estimate.

Comment: It depends on a lot of things. By “fusion fuel,” do you mean heavy water (D2O and T2O) or hydrogen gas (D2 and H2)? If it’s kept in gaseous form, what pressure is it compressed to? How much does the starship weigh aside from the fuel? A ship that weighs 1 kg can go much faster off of 1,767 cubic feet of fuel than a ship that weighs 1,000,000,000 kg.

Comment: What’s the operating principle of the engine? Do we assume that 100% of the energy output from the fusion reaction is converted into kinetic energy of the exhaust? Do we take into account the fact that the ship will have to slow down again when it reaches its destination, or do we ignore that part?

Comment: The fuel is hydrogen gas at 10 psi. The propulsion tank is spherical. There are two reactor chambers, one to speed up and the other to slow down.

Comment: As one limit, calculate the energy one can get from fusing all of your hydrogen (H, D, T??) and compare with the relativistic kinetic energy of your body at 0.5c.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question much more suited to [worldbuilding.se] where science related question dealing with fictional technology are dealt with.

Answer (score 1):

Given the OP's numbers, the payload will not attain relativistic speeds unless it is quite small.  To show this, we'll make a bunch of unrealistically optimistic assumptions and show that the mass of the payload must end up being pretty small.

We will assume that the entire fusion energy of the fuel is converted into the KE of the payload.  Of course, this is entirely unrealistic;  in reality, a significant portion of the reaction energy will be imparted to the fuel itself, and thermodynamics will impose further limits.In comments, the OP specified a tank of hydrogen gas at 10 psi.  Let's assume a temperature of 20 K, so that it's as dense as possible but still gaseous.  Using the ideal gas law, we can estimate the number of hydrogen atoms in this tank as $N = 2\frac{PV}{kT}$, which [works out to be](https://www.google.com/search?q=%281767+cubic+feet%29*%2810+psi%29%2F%28boltzmann+constant+*+20+Kelvin%29*2&client=safari&rls=en&sxsrf=ALeKk03dEXAhjrUsmCzQqVnUZbXKn4dtwA%3A1625000913584&ei=0YvbYI6BI9-s5NoPmuq--A8&oq=%281767+cubic+feet%29*%2810+psi%29%2F%28boltzmann+constant+*+20+Kelvin%29*2&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgjECcyBAgjECcyBAgjECc6BwgAEEcQsANKBAhBGABQvOwNWLzsDWCPow5oAXACeACAAV6IAZIBkgEBMpgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjOrdqR4L3xAhVfFlkFHRq1D_8Q4dUDCA4&uact=5) about $N \approx 2.5 \times 10^{28}$.  (The factor of two comes from the fact that there are 2 hydrogen atoms per molecule in the gas.)

Now, we'll assume that we've mastered deuterium-tritium fusion, and have managed to breed tritium in the reactor for this purpose.  This reaction releases about 8.8 MeV of energy per hydrogen atom fused.  If this energy all goes into the KE of the payload (and again—I cannot stress this enough—this is an unrealistic assumption), the payload will get [an energy of](https://www.google.com/search?q=2.499e28+*+8.79+MeV&client=safari&rls=en&sxsrf=ALeKk03d6WiU8hcPi2tdwPqTkpMEQZGrwg%3A1625001148335&ei=vIzbYPf_E7uw5NoP6Omj4Ag&oq=2.499e28+*+8.79+MeV&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQghEKsCOgQIIxAnOgUIABCRAjoFCC4QsQM6BQgAELEDOg4ILhCxAxCDARDHARCjAjoECAAQQzoCCAA6BQghEKABSgQIQRgAUMivJFj2gSVghYUlaARwAngAgAF-iAHBDZIBBDIyLjKYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwj3zdKB4b3xAhU7GFkFHej0CIwQ4dUDCA4&uact=5) $K \approx 3.3 \times 10^{16}$ J. If the object is to be travelling at $0.5c$ with this amount of kinetic energy, then its Lorentz factor will be $\gamma = 1/\sqrt{1 - 0.5^2} = 2/\sqrt{3}$, and so its rest mass will be
$$
K = (\gamma - 1) m c^2 \quad \Rightarrow \quad m = \frac{K}{(2/\sqrt{3} - 1) c^2}
$$
which [works out to $m \approx 2.5$ kg.](https://www.google.com/search?q=3.519e16+joules+%2F+%28%282%2Fsqrt%283%29+-+1%29*speed+of+light%5E2%29&client=safari&rls=en&sxsrf=ALeKk02rz1r1PD52Pp632Sa0sQhHRdfCFQ%3A1625001755857&ei=G4_bYLnfM--q5NoPuYGFqAQ&oq=3.519e16+joules+%2F+%28%282%2Fsqrt%283%29+-+1%29*speed+of+light%5E2%29&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgAEEcQsAM6AggAOgQIABAeOgUIIRCgAToHCCEQChCgAToFCCEQqwI6CgghEAoQoAEQiwNKBAhBGABQwMsQWLbgEWDE5BFoAXACeAGAAe8BiAHcIJIBBjQ3LjMuMZgBAKABAqABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQK4AQLAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwj52Kqj473xAhVvFVkFHblAAUUQ4dUDCA4&uact=5)  I doubt that you could build a tank to hold the hydrogen with this mass, let alone an artificial gravity ring.

In reality, the situation is much, much worse that this;  the exponential properties of the rocket equation mean that you'd actually need far, far more fuel than I've mentioned here to get a payload of 2.5 kg up to $0.5c$.  A more detailed calculation would require details about the rocket's exhaust velocity, reaction mass, reaction type, reactor efficiency, and probably some stuff I haven't mentioned to boot.  The above calculation is mainly to show that the provided numbers don't even get you close to the speed of light for a reasonably sized crewed spacecraft.

Comment: If the OP was willing to replace gaseous hydrogen with liquid hydrogen then they would get approximately 85 times as much fuel mass. So in the unrealistic scenario of all energy being converted to KE, this would be enough to accelerate two, or even three non-obese, astronauts to the required velocity. I haven't allowed for the mass of space-suits, oxygen, food, water etc. - but that is no problem as the proposed scenario has no provision for deceleration at the other end of their journey, so they are going to be dead on 'arrival' regardless.